# Debug pipenv tasks.py task in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I've inherited a python project that I can start via `pipenv invoke app.start`.  It looks like app.start is defined in a tasks.py.

How can I set up vscode to debug this project so I can set breakpoints?

I've got the venv selected as my interpreter in vscode.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find the `pipenv invoke` command in the doc and the repo

Comment: can you show a stripped down version of `tasks.py`, how does it implement the `names to function mappings`

Answer (score 1):

The entry point to [invoke](https://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/) is a Python script that should be in your virtual environment's `bin` directory (on the same level as the `python` file). E.g. `/Users/<user>/.virtualenvs/<virtual-env>/bin/invoke`.

If you have the path to your Python interpreter, you can replace `python` with `invoke` in the `"program"` value below.

You can create a Python VS Code debugging configuration (`launch.json`) as follows to run the `invoke` script with any given arguments in the `"args"` value:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Start app",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "path/to/virtualenv/invoke",
            "args": ["app.start"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: AWESOME. Worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: No `invoke` in my virtualenv at all, is this something added on?

Comment: @brandonscript yes, it's this package: https://www.pyinvoke.org/